# Does the Cycle Property hold when edges values are non distinct?

Tags: graph-theory

Will the Cycle Property hold when we have non-distinct edges?

It seems like we should still be able to state that some edge will not be part of ANY MST when a connection can be made with smaller weight edges.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree#Cycle_property

Comment: What is "the Cycle Property"?

Comment: added cycle property link to question

Comment: I don't see any place in the proof at the links where it is assumed that the edge values are distinct; all that is assumed is that there's a cycle where one edge has greater weight than any of the others in that cycle.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ok-- that was my confusion. I had seen a couple proofs where distinct edges were assumed-- and others where distinct/non-distinct was not mentioned. But, none where non-distinct edges were assumed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's incorrect. Imagine a square (four-cycle) with two adjacent edges having weight 1, and the other two edges having weight 2. Every spanning tree of this graph has at least one weight 2 edge, because otherwise the vertex connecting the weight 2 edges would be isolated.

This doesn't mean that the cycle property fails to hold. This just means that you can't find an edge with weight larger than all the others, so you can't use the property to eliminate said edge.

Comment: Sure, but in that case we wouldn't be able to state that the 2 weight edge (from A-B) isn't in any MST-- as a path from A-B cannot be created with edges strictly smaller than our 2 weight edge

Comment: Yes, that's my point. I think I misunderstood your question, judging by the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer is yes.

You are using cycle property to know if an edge is not in any MST.
In Jon Kleinberg's book on algorithm design, on pages 147 to 149, there is a complete discussion about cycle property.
What I understood from the book is that to know if an edge is not in any MST it is sufficient to find a path from one of its vertices to the other one not including edges with weight heavier than or equal to the mentioned edge.
Also you can see an algorithm for this problem on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049864/check-if-edge-is-included-in-some-mst-in-linear-time-non-distinct-values/40433919).